# Use XtraDB as a storage engine in a Spring Boot & Hibernate application

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, mariadb

I am working on a project using Spring Boot 2.0.3, Hibernate 5.2.17 and MariaDB 10.1.29. And I am trying to set the storage engine to XtraDB when hibernate generates the tables, but without success.

Here is my application.properties file:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/bookstore-db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=12
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=300000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1200000
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=xtradb

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Even with specifying `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=xtradb` it still use InnoDB as shown in the console:

```
create table hibernate_sequence (
   next_val bigint
) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 

insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: 

create table user (
   id_user bigint not null,
    email varchar(255) not null,
    enabled bit not null,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    password varchar(255),
    phone varchar(255),
    username varchar(255),
    primary key (id_user)
) engine=InnoDB
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just use InnoDB.

Comment: The problem is that for MariaDB versions below 10.2 it's recommended to use XtraDB for performance reasons [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/choosing-the-right-storage-engine)

Comment: Yes, XtraDB is better.  For 1% of  applications.  The other 99% won't notice a significant difference.

Comment: Ok man, I saw your profile and I think you are very experienced, so I'll take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, InnoDB is used as default and best choice since MariaDB 10.2. These are the reasons mentioned on their [site](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-does-mariadb-102-use-innodb-instead-of-xtradb/)

> XtraDB had many great improvements over InnoDB in 5.1 and 5.5. But over time, MySQL has implemented almost all of them. InnoDB has caught up and XtraDB is only marginally better...
>
> In particular, the only real improvement that XtraDB 5.7 seems to have is for a write-intensive I/O-bound workload, where innodb_thread_concurrency control is disabled.

So there is no more reasons to switch to XtraDB for those using the latest versions of MariaDB.